# Data link between multiple websites?

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, c#-4.0

I have a .NET web application which needs to feed data to 5 separately hosted websites.  For speed reasons the data needs to be periodically cached on each individual website rather than requested 'live'.

We are talking maybe 10MB of data, although possibly hundreds of MB of pictures.

We could transfer the data over using XML feeds but are there other options which I should consider? Should we be looking at using Web Services to provide the necessary link?

The 5 websites will be written in PHP or .NET but if it facilitates the data transfer maybe .NET would be best.

Comment: Take a look at the rich features of WCF services

Answer (score 1):

Pulling in that amount of data from that variety of sources will probably lead to a low performance site (even with caching as that would have to be huge). I'd suggest setting up web services for the data transfer, however, I'd also be looking at storing a copy local to this web app. Perhaps in a database or file system on the server. If you're worried about keeping the two in sync, you could always trash the copy every night and run a full transfer again.